# How to write a "UTF-16" encoding File over FTP in java

Tags: java, encoding, ftp, sftp, filewriter

I want to write a file directly in the FTP server using java and which needs to be in the UTF-16 format so that I can have support of latin,chinese,etc. characters .

Any suggestion will be of great help.

Thanks in advance.:))

Answer (score 2):

Well, to start with it *doesn't* need to be UTF-16 to support all characters - I'd recommend UTF-8 instead of UTF-16.

However, basically you should transfer it as if it's a just a binary file (in binary mode in FTP). That way the bytes will be transferred with no textual interpretation so the two ends don't need to agree on an encoding at all.

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for you help. But I am trying to directly write to an FTP server folder from my application , and not do an FTP transfer to that folder location. Can u suggest ways for writing it in the FTP server folder location having UTF-8 encoding.. :)) Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: @user2648569: I don't see what you mean. How do you intend to "directly write to an FTP folder" without doing an FTP transfer. What do you think the difference is? And is it the contents of the file which is non-ASCII or he file name itself?

Answer (score 0):

To convert a String to or from UTF-8 and UTF-16 just use the String functions provided, there is a tutorial on them here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html